# Cannot uninstall angular-cli checks for updates instead of uninstalling

Tags: angular

I'm running the following command to uninstall angular cli:

> npm uninstall -g @angular-cli

and it checks for updates instead of uninstalling it. Here's what I get after running that:

> up to date in 0.067s

I read that I had to uninstall the package before the cli running the same command without the "@" sign before angular-cli. But even like that I get that error.

My angular cli version is: 6.0.8

Do you know of another method to uninstall it?

Thank you!

Comment: Try this `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`

Comment: I get the same (up to date in 0.058s)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for some reason, I solved this issue just replacing the "-" on angular-cli for a "/".
So the final command is:

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

Hope it helps someone!

Edit:

As Ulrich says in a comment: "You uninstall what you install". That stands for every package you install haha

Comment: And thats what is everywhere. Even of the official documentation [https://cli.angular.io/](https://cli.angular.io/) and [https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki)

Comment: Hmmm well, when I was looking for the uninstall method, everyone did it with the "-".

Comment: You uninstall what you install. Thats fine. Happy you solved your issue by yourself. In fact it may help

Comment: Yeah, just a while later I thought about trying the same way I installed it. My bad hehe, you learn something new everyday! I'll actually take your comment and paste in the answer haha, that's useful too